# HRESULT exceptions

Tags: .net, win32exception

Is there any lists where the error codes are explained. Eks: HRESULT: 0x81070215 does not tell me enything about what when wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
WinError.h
```

I have this at the following path on my machine, yours will be similar as well:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\include\WinError.h
```

BTW, if you have Visual Studio installed, then there is a tool available named 'Error Lookup'. Go to Visual Studio, Tools->Error Lookup and in it you can put any HRESULT code to get it's description. You can download ErrorLookup from [this location](http://www.toggle.com/lv/group/view/kl54436/Windows_Error_Lookup_Tool.htm) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `HRESULT` codes are defined by the code that is causing them to happen, so there is no unique list - it depends on the server code as to what they mean. Normally, you want to look at the [error info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221032.aspx) for the current thread, and see what additional information is passed along with it, in order for it to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error look tool in VS's Tools menu (`Tools->Error Lookup`), also you can find tool here

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\errlook.exe
```