# What does COM Error 80010105 mean and where to find other codes?

Tags: com

Is there a list of COM error codes somewhere?

**Related:** [HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973206/hresult-0x80010105-rpc-e-serverfault-question)

Comment: where do you get this error ?

Comment: When trying to instantiate a class from a COM library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HRESULT exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356528/hresult-exceptions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Standard COM Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee824990%28CS.10%29.aspx) (at least for Microsoft Commerce Server):

> The following table shows the most common standard COM errors returned
>   by the properties and methods of the Commerce Server objects:

```
Constant    Value (32-bit)  Description
S_OK            00000000    The standard return value used to communicate successful completion.
S_FALSE         00000001    An alternate success value, typically used to communicate successful, but non-standard completion. The precise meaning depends on the method or property in question.
E_UNEXPECTED    8000FFFF    Catastrophic failure error.
E_NOTIMPL       80004001    Not implemented error.
E_OUTOFMEMORY   8007000E    Out of memory error.
E_INVALIDARG    80070057    One or more arguments are not valid error.
E_NOINTERFACE   80004002    Interface not supported error.
E_POINTER       80004003    Pointer not valid error.
E_HANDLE        80070006    Handle not valid error.
E_ABORT         80004004    Operation aborted error.
E_FAIL          80004005    Unspecified error.
E_ACCESSDENIED  80070005    General access denied error.
```

[Com Errors Search Engine](http://www.comerrors.com/)

Comment: At the time of this comment (August 2012), the COM Errors Search Engine link points to a website that includes content from jfrsttc.freewww.biz, a site currently classified by Google as a known to distributor of malware.

Comment: At the time of this comment, the COM Errors Search Engine site is broken and replies to all queries with `HTTP 500`.

Comment: At the time of this comment, I wish someone had answered the first part of the question! Still need to know, "What does COM Error 80010105 mean?"

Comment: The still-existing link doesn't include the error which was asked about. The other link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

I got following information from the Windows Kits header file WinError.h:

```
//
// MessageId: RPC_E_SERVERFAULT
//
// MessageText:
//
// The server threw an exception.
//
#define RPC_E_SERVERFAULT                _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80010105L)
```